# How to make navbar dropdown float above all elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui

I am trying to create a navbar dropdown using material design. It is working fine. The only problem I have is that all the other elements are floating above the dropdown.

[image: Screenshot]

What I want is that dropdown should float above all the other elements. I have used "z-index", but it's not working.

```css
element.style {
    transform: none;
    transition: transform 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}

.makeStyles-dropdownMenu-81 {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.makeStyles-root-80 {
    width: 10%;
    max-width: 360px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.MuiList-padding {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.MuiList-root {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

nav {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="MuiList-root makeStyles-root-80 makeStyles-dropdownMenu-81 MuiList-padding" aria-label="mailbox folders" style="transform: none; transition: transform 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;">
  <div class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiListItemText-primary MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Inbox</span>
    </div>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </div>
  
  <hr class="MuiDivider-root">
  
  <div class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-divider MuiListItem-button" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiListItemText-primary MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Drafts</span>
    </div>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiListItemText-primary MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Trash</span>
    </div>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </div>
  
  <hr class="MuiDivider-root MuiDivider-light">
  
  <div class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="MuiListItemText-root">
      <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiListItemText-primary MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Spam</span>
    </div>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Link: https://surroundinganchovy.htmlpasta.com/

It will be helpful if I can get some suggestion.

Comment: These kind of issue should not happen when you using material UI but since you using Material UI + ant design + Bootstrap + your own CSS it will create such issues. Select any single UI framework for your project first.

Comment: @RohitAmbre This project is for me to test various frameworks, that's why you see all the other frameworks imported. But if you notice carefully, my navbar and the card shown, have been built using material-ui only. Also, the class names should not conflict as all the imported frameworks are using different naming conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you would have to do is apply a `position: relative;` to the parent element (either the header or the div that is used for the navigation item) so that the z-index of the descendants/children in that parent element is actually applied.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The header should have a relative position.

```
.MuiAppBar-positionStatic {
    position: relative;
}
```

or

```
header {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a z-index to the parent component that is the sibling of the chart component. In this case it's `<header>`. So in JSX you can do:

```
<header style={{ position: "absolute", zIndex: 100 }}>
  /** -- snip -- **/
</header>
```

Or you can add a class to do this for you. It has to be done like this because z-index's only affect their siblings. So only sibling divs can have z-index's that overlap eachother.

This is a very common problem with modals etc. The z-index is inherited from any parents above the div; This is known as the stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: If I add ``` position: "absolute" ``` in header, then all other elements position changes.

Comment: The problem with this is that the contents will then need to be shifted downwards by an unknown amount of pixels. See [Sir Exotic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62405625/732284) for a better approach.